# I need to store arabic data into my sql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone I know that this subject has been posted many times but none of them work for me .
So I need to store some arabic data in particular table but when I send it and explore it within phpmyadmin I found something like this &#1575 i try to add the meta charset=utf-8 in head and add accept-charset='utf-8' in the form  but still no difference  here's the code that i use it to connect to my database

```html
$conect=new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$datab;charset=utf8;connection collation: utf8_general_ci",$user,$pass);
$conect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql="INSERT INTO botola_team(name,nameabbreviation,team_url,year_of_ta2sis,President,coach,name_field,pic_of_team,logo,pic_field)
VALUES ('$name','$nameabrev','$teamurl','$ta2sis','$president','$coach','$namefield','$teampic','$logo','$teampic')";
$conect->exec($sql);
```

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBPub.png)

Comment: Show your databse schema. Column which store arabic data should have `utf8_general_ci` charset.

Comment: i already do that
i have the column name with utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: thnx it work i was using utf8_unicode_ci insead of utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `utf8_general_ci` instead of `utf8_unicode_ci` charset in table column.